# Serialization of WorkflowServices with Protobuf-net

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation-4, protobuf-net

Background: I had a process for putting new products into a product database which allowed clients to make a WCF call and send a raw product object into a method that did various processing.  This method had become unwieldy and difficult to maintain so I decided to replace the method with a workflow service.  I already had my operation contract interface from my original process so I created a workflow service that implemented the same interface (using the technique outlined here [Workflow Service that Consumes an Existing Contract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh305676.aspx) ).  Following the steps in the link just mentioned results in an auto generated send/receive pair activity for the methods in the original operation contract.  These activities are then used in the workflow service.  Therefore the clients didn't have to change anything as they were still using the original contract.

This new workflow service is hosted in IIS.  In the configuration I am specifying a behaviourConfiguration on both the service and client which should result in WCF using protobuf-net for serialization.  This WCF configuration is the same as the original process except the address is now the workflow service file (a .xamlx file) rather than the original .svc file.   However, when the service is a WF4 workflow service this behaviourConfiguration is causing problems (basically it doesn't work and any data I send into the workflow ends up being null).  If I remove this serialization behavior everything works as expected.

My question therefore is is it possible to use protobuf-net serialization with workflow services?  I have read this article [Configuring Serialization in Workflow Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff742829.aspx) and it suggests that because workflow services are WCF services we have a choice of serialization, but then goes on to list only the two basic options (in the first sentence).  I would have thought we could change this somehow to add our own options for serialization, but can't see any straightforward way to do it.

My service contract looks as follows:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://www.MyCompany.com/services/", Name = "NewProductApprovalWorkflow")]
[ContractClass(typeof(NewProductApprovalWorkflowContracts))]
public interface INewProductApprovalWorkflow
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Instantiates a new product approval workflow.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="product"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [OperationContract]
    Product StartNewProductApprovalWorkflow(Product product);

    /// <summary>
    /// Approves the product for approval in the product catalog
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="product"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [OperationContract]
    Product CompleteProductApprovalWorkflow(Product product, ProductApproval approvalInfo);

}
```

The "Product" and "ProductApproval" objects are too large to post here, but are basically primitive types and have been well tested from a serialization perspective (they are used throughout our platform on many different WCF services, all of which use the protobuf-net behavior without any problems).

Also, I enabled message logging on WCF and I can see the proto node in the message is populated with the serialized object (both in the client send log and the wcf receive log).  Tracing the output from service model, activities and service model messages doesn't show any other errors except those resulting from the null object that the wf service tries to use.

Any ideas or advice welcome!

Comment: Not every type is automatically Serializable via protobuf-net; workflow types would surprise me if they worked without any configuration. What is the error message?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but to my mind the serialization should be independent of any workflow types.  I defined the contract that is used by the send/receive activities and it is only those activities that I want to use protobuf-net for.  If the workflow can't use protobuf internally for serialization (e.g. persistence) that is ok, but for the wcf communication I would have thought we could use the full range of wcf config options.  The error message is being swallowed by the workflow as it runs ok except the wcf message data is null.  I will enable tracing and get back to you with the error.

Comment: so just to clarify my scenario, I am implementing a workflow service on an existing contract as per this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh305676.aspx

Comment: what I'm saying is: it depends on what ***exactly*** the data-contract that you are sending looks like. You can swap the serializer, but different serializers can have different requirements. What is the data that is being sent?

Comment: @MarcGravell - I have updated the question to give more detail, but basically the data being sent is a type (Product) that I am serializing else where using protobuf without any issues.  I have enabled tracing and the only errors I can see are issued by the workflow when it hits the null object (i.e. I can't see any errors thrown by either the wcf tracing or the wf tracing relating to serialization).